# Developer dashboard - is there an API for it?

Tags: dashboard

I'd like to be able to export all data displayed on the Developer Dashboard for a given request.

Is there an API available for this?

Comment: In SharePoint 2013, I understand that DD runs on a dedicated WCF service called [diagnosticsdata.svc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj175977.aspx).  I haven't used this web service, but it might be useful to you.

Comment: Did you see that? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cd96757-9b56-4f32-81b0-9e61b4f3f1ab/export-developer-dashboard-data?forum=sharepointgeneral